# Create a 24 hour 1 min resolution data set in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a 1 min resolution time series contained in a `pandas` data frame. What is the easiest (and most efficient) way for me to pad these times series in such way that on each date present in the data frame I have 1 min time steps for all 1 min intervals (so the date would have 24 hours worth of 1 min data steps)? If there is no data for a given point in time, it should have an NA instead of a value. For example, if I have data for 11-Nov-2012 from 2am to 6pm and data for 16-Nov-2012 from 3pm to 11pm, I want 24 hours of 1 min data points for both dates with NAs attached to the time stamps where there is no data.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could give a short example dataframe (which we can copy, paste and go) as well as what you want its result to be, see [sscce.org](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `resample` method (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#up-and-downsampling) if you have a time series (if the time is used as the index):

```
df.resample('1min')
```

EDIT:

Something like:

```
rng1 = date_range('2012-11-11', '2012-11-12', freq='1min')
rng2 = date_range('2012-11-16', '2012-11-17', freq='1min')
rng = rng1 + rng2

df.reindex(rng)
```

Comment: Actually, this data frame is already a concatenation of re-sampled data in OHLC format. The problem is that re-sampling does not give me missing 1 min intervals, just the time intervals from starting time to end time during each date. Feels to me like the trick is to select all unique dates present, create 24 hour time samples for each of these dates and merge the two sets.

Comment: OK, then indeed, the easiest way will probably be to create an index object with the date range you want and to reindex the dataframe.